# Openning PDF within app. Not working. Help needed

Tags: java, android, pdf

Relatively new to this. I have an issue of opening a pdf within the app itself.  I can do open urls and let the user surf within the app but I am having an issue with PDFs.  I am using docs.google.com/gview to do this but It is not working for some reasonI get an error from Google 414.  Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





    WebView theWebPage = new WebView(this);
       setContentView(theWebPage);

       theWebPage.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       theWebPage.zoomIn();

     theWebPage.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");


     theWebPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



   //theWebPage.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);


       theWebPage.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


               String url2 = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url;

             view.loadUrl(url2);

               //view.loadUrl(url);

               return false;
           }
       });





}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

ALL the links on the page are pdf.  How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

414 is url too long.  I think you have an infinite loop- your shouldOverrideUrlLoading is called each time you load the page.  It calls loadPage on a new, longer URL.  This calls shouldOverrideUrlLoading again.  This loops until you go over the size limit of a URL.  shouldOverrideUrlLoading should never call loadPage.  Instead it should return true if you want to override the URL, and false otherwise.  At the very least you should check and not call loadPage if the url starts with http://docs.google.com/gview

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this library to show the PDF files in your application
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library